# Does analyticity of integrand imply integral is analytic or asymptotic to power series?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, asymptotics, analyticity

Consider a 2-dimensional surface integral over the boundary, $\partial V$ of some region $V$ in 3-dimensional Euclidean space,

\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}_{\partial V}(\vec{x})\equiv \int_{\partial V} d\vec{\Sigma}_2(\vec{y}) \cdot\vec{f}(\vec{y},\vec{x}),
\end{align}
where $d\vec{\Sigma}_2(\vec{y})$ is meant to denote the surface element on $\partial V$.

On the surface, suppose $\vec{f}$ is analytic in $\vec{y}$, $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}-\vec{x}$.

**Question:**  Under what conditions will the surface integral $\mathcal{I}_{\partial V}(\vec{x})$ be either analytic in $\vec{x}$ or asymptotic to a power series in $\vec{x}$?  By power series in $\vec{x}$, I mean
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}_{\partial V}(\vec{x})=\sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^3}\frac{c_\alpha}{\alpha!}x^\alpha, 
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ is a multi-index so $\alpha!\equiv\prod_{i=1}^3 \alpha_i$.

Comment: I guess we might as well ask the same thing about the 1-D case on a line: when is $\int_a^b f(x,y)\,dy = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas  
I thought about making that simplification, but I had a specific application in mind and wasn't sure whether there might be some subtlety related to the dimension. I'm not sure if your comment was just meant to claim there should be no such subtlety or whether you are also implying the answer should be 'obvious' from the one dimensional case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to cause confusion. I just think the situation is analogous, so the results in one case are probably similar to those in the other. That said, I'm not sure what the "right" conditions are.